# achieving Synchronized behavior with ThreadPoolExecutor using SynchronousQueue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am writing a service class that is supposed have two modes: synchronous and asynchronous.

```
public class ProcessorImpl implements IProcessor {

    private final MyRepo repo;
    private final Jobrunner runner;
    private final boolean isAsync;


    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @ProcessorImpl
    public ProcessorImpl(final MyRepo repo,
                              final Jobrunner runner) {
        this(repo, runner, false);
    }

    public ProcessorImpl(final MyRepo repo,
                              final Jobrunner runner,
                              final boolean isAsync) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.runner = runner;
        this.isAsync = isAsync;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        if (isAsync) {          
            executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50));
        } else {
            executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response doAction(final Request request, final String id) {
        if (isAsync) {
            //submit task and return incomplete response with id
        } else {
            //submit task and get result and return response that is returned by Callable
        }
    }
}
```

The switching is driven by the `isAsync` flag.

When Synchronous, I want to be able to submit the task, get the completed response from task submission and use it to build the `Response` to return. For this mode, I am using `SynchronousQueue`.

When Async mode is on, just submit the task and return immediately with incomplete response. For this mode I am using `LinkedBlockingQueue`to wait the tasks in the queue.

I have two questions in regards to Synchronous mode:

1. How do I get the result back and give response in a synchronous way? I am unsure how to use `Future` here.
2. What if another commands task comes in while thread was processing the task? Will it get rejected? How can I avoid rejection?

Any help with some code samples will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you not afraid of `RejectedExecutionException` with `new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>())`?

Comment: @akuzminykh actually my second question is about how to avoid this instance when commands come faster than they are processed. These `doAction` are all initiated by Rest calls request/response, some want complete result, some ok with incomplete and query later time.

Comment: You can e.g. use the [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler)) constructor and give it `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`, which will just let the caller execute the task. There are more. You can even implement one yourself.

Comment: ok, will be good to see an example. And any issue if in this main thread I am doing `Future. get()` call waiting for the result of the first command ?

Comment: I would not use isAsync flag. I would do 2 different classes. SyncProcessorImpl with method doAction which returns Future<Response>, and ASyncProcessorImpl with method doAction which returns Response and does all calculations directly, without thread pool.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov thanks I like this. Would be great to see an example with pattern :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant ASyncProcessorImpl with method doAction which returns Future<Response>, and SyncProcessorImpl with method doAction which returns Response

Comment: Actually ASync needs to return immediate response to incoming request for me. But this response isn’t the complete one, just initial half baked. Later client query for more. I Want to avoid duplication of the calc logic in two classes too.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class SyncProcessorImpl {
    private final MyRepo repo;
    private final Jobrunner runner;

    public SyncProcessorImpl (final MyRepo repo, final Jobrunner runner) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.runner = runner;
    }

    public Response doAction(final Request request, final String id) {
        // do all calculations directly and return complete response
    }
}

public class AsyncProcessorImpl extends SyncProcessorImpl {
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public AsyncProcessorImpl(final MyRepo repo, final Jobrunner runner) {
        super(repo, runner);
        executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(50));
    }

    public Future<Response> doActionAsync(final Request request, final String id) {
        //submit task and return future that is returned by submit(Callable)
       return executorService.submit(()->super.doActionc(request, id));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, as this is framework, it needs to support both implementation which your answer gives. However, other projects that have this on their classpath, should be able to choose which mode, sync or async bean..this is what I am struggling with hence the `isAsync` flag